# findFragmentById возвращает null

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь динамически заменять фрагменты, если создавать объект, то работает. Пытаюсь получить фрагмент по его id, возвращает null. Не вижу в чем ошибка.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

item1 it1;

FragmentTransaction ft;
FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    it1 = new item1();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
    ft.commit();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch(id){
        case R.id.nav_item1: ft.replace(R.id.containter, (item1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_item1)); break;
        //case R.id.nav_item1: ft.replace(R.id.containter, it1); break; <-- так работает
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

}

**item1.java**

```
public class item1 extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
public static final String TAG = "item1Tag";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public item1() {
}

public static item1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    item1 fragment = new item1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("qqq","item2 "+this);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item1, container, false);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

**fragment_item1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_item1"
tools:context="com.example.robot.test.fragments.item1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView style="@style/textViewFr1"
    android:text="@string/_1"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView style="@style/textViewFr1"
    android:text="@string/_2"
    android:background="#0F0"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView style="@style/textViewFr1"
    android:text="@string/_3"
    android:background="#00F"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в одном из мест Вы вообще комитите пустую транзакцию:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //Здесь предполагается что-то делать с фрагментами: add, replace, remove, etc
    ft.commit();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Во-вторых, в другом месте, там где у Вас `switch`, Вы пытаетесь заменить фрагмент на другой, который уже добавлен к активити, что будет приводить к ошибке `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`. Аргументами в методах `add` и `replace` должны быть фрагменты, которые в данный момент не добавлены на активити, чаще всего это только созданные фрагменты.

В-третьих, в качестве параметра метода `findFragmentById` надо указывать `id` **контейнера** фрагмента, а не `id` корневого элемента фрагмента, как это сделано у Вас. То есть надо `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.containter)`, а не `fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_item1)`. Но, повторюсь ещё раз, это приведёт к `IllegalStateException`. Вам нужно создать фрагмент заново (с помощью `new`) или взять кэшированный фрагмент, если Вы уверены, что он не добавлен к активити (у такого фрагмента `isAdded() == false`).

Answer (score 0):

Для чего вы пытаетесь получить фрагмент посредством `fm`, если вы его туда (в контейнер) не добавляете?
Создав Instance вашего фрагмента, вы и так сможете динамически заменять фрагменты. Только советую воспользоваться `newInstance(String param1, String param2)` фрагмента для его инициализации, вместо конструктора `item1()`. Это позволит избежать ненужного дублирования одного и того же фрагмента.

То есть инициализация фрагмента должна выглядеть так: `it1  = newInstance("", "")`. 
Замена фрагмента в контейнере будет выглядеть точно так же, как написано у вас в строке, которая помещена в комментарий.

И, как указал другой комментатор, у вас в `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` пустая транзакция.